# Delphi: show 'characters remaining ' in the status bar

Tags: delphi

I have various cxTextedit's on my form with maxlenght set in the designer.
How can I implement the functionality so that my dxstatusbar1 shows
the characters remaining for each of the cxTextEdit boxes when I begin typing in them ?

Comment: Is there OnChange event for cxTextEdit? If yes, check Length in this event handler and compare with maxlength

Comment: Right now I have ;  dxStatusBar1.Panels[0].Text := 'Maximum number of characters : ' + inttostr(cxTextEdit5.Properties.MaxLength); But how do I subtract?

Comment: MaxLength - Length ?

Comment: No 'lenght' property...

Comment: Length is function that is passed a string

Comment: I get : [dcc32 Error] Unit14.pas(234): E2010 Incompatible types: 'string' and 'Integer' using this :dxStatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := cxTextEdit5.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxTextEdit5.Text);

Comment: @user763539 Perhaps it's worth you spending a little time reviewing Delphi types, integers and strings. You really need to have that knowledge hard wired so that such error messages are instantly recognisable.

Comment: You have already used IntToStr function in the first comment.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The number of characters remain is found using this expression:

```
cxTextEdit5.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxTextEdit5.Text);
```

This is an integer. To convert an integer into a string, which you need to do in order to set the status bar text, pass the integer to `IntToStr`.

Comment: Do I need to convert this to integer first ? dxStatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := cxTextEdit5.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxTextEdit5.Text); wont work ...

Comment: Well yes you do need to do that. You clearly already know how to do that though judging from the comments so I didn't feel it necessary to tell you how to convert an integer into a string. Anyway, I've edited the answer to include that now.

Comment: inttostr(cxTextEdit5.Properties.MaxLength) - inttostr.Length(cxTextEdit5.Text); I get [dcc32 Error] Unit14.pas(234): E2250 There is no overloaded version of 'IntToStr' that can be called with these arguments

Comment: This does not work either : dxStatusBar1.Panels[1].Text := intToStr(cxTextEdit5.Properties.MaxLength) - inttostr(Length(cxTextEdit5.Text));

Comment: IntToStr(cxTextEdit5.Properties.MaxLength - Length(cxTextEdit5.Text))

Comment: Just an FYI, `TControl` has a public `GetTextLen()` method that `TWinControl` overrides to use the `WM_GETTEXTLENGTH` message, which is more efficient than using `Length(Text)`. I do not know if `TcxTextEdit` is a `TGraphicControl` or `TWinControl` descendant, but if the latter than you should use `GetTextLen()`: `cxTextEdit5.Properties.MaxLength - cxTextEdit5.GetTextLen`